# How to make uploading large (more than 1MB) files work with nginx, rails and uploadify

Tags: nginx, debian, ruby-on-rails, ruby, upload

I have problem with my production nginx configuration (on my development machine with mongrel everything works). My environment is: nginx as proxy, rainbows as backend running rails 3.1 application with ruby 1.9.2.

When I'm trying to upload large file (more than 1MB) I see 502 error on my website and in nginx error log file:

```
2012/04/02 14:45:17 [error] 14415#0: *658 sendfile() failed (32: Broken pipe) while sending request to upstream, ....
```

What I've tried:

- setting client_max_body_size 5m;
- keepalive_timeout  600;

Uploading smaller files works fine. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time I've found that you have to repeat max file upload size setting in rainbows configuration file:

```
client_max_body_size(2 * 1024 * 1024)
```